# error mocha unsupported node 5.5.x

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js

I try to run Grunt task but it says my Mocha version does not support nodejs 5.5.0. Is there a way to fix this or do i need to install an older version of nodejs?

```
Running "mochaTest:src" (mochaTest) task
>> Mocha exploded!
>> Error: Unsupported Node version: 5.5.0
```

Comment: Second this. I can't elaborate enough on how frustrating it is trying to get started with a new stack and failing dependencies prevent it from working out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in one of the packages: `mock-fs`.
Go to your `package.json` and change somewhere where it reads:

```
"mock-fs": "~3.4.0",
```

or similar, to:

```
"mock-fs": "~3.7.0",
```

Then run:

```
$ npm i
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by navigating to :C:\Users\khaled\Documents\NorthwindNode\mean\node_modules\mock-fs\lib\index.js. Then, I added the Node JS version I am using to end of var versions = { } object. This solved the problem> I hope it solves you problem too